# send strings between two distant computers in python

Tags: python, networking

i'm trying to send strings to a distant computer (by that i mean a computer thats not in LAN)
i've tried UPNP to automatically set up a port forwarding rule to redirect the router traffic to the computer thats supposed to receive the string but it's not working (prolly cause of the firewall or other protections) and it's not very safe , i've seeked for answers online but only found some socket code but that only worked in LAN .

i expect a computer to be able to send a string to another across the internet , and not on the same network , as fast as possible and decentralized , without the need for the user to do anything and mainly on windows

Comment: How about Email?

Comment: i don't think email would be appropriate mainly cause i'm trying to make it so the user have to do the least amount of things possible , that'd also require the user's email and password

Comment: Maybe you can click [edit] and be more precise about what you are really trying to achieve and what the constraints are. You haven't mentioned data volume, data rate, acceptable latency, security, operating system, user effort/skill level, reliability...

Comment: @MarkSetchell done , i've tried to add as much details as i could , it's mainly to try to get it working so for now any data rate , latency is acceptable

Comment: You can use thrid party messaging services like Telegram or Whatsapp APIs..
Try having two different accounts opened on the two computers and send from one to the other.

Comment: @hacker315 you mentionned than both computers needed to have an account , and thats something i'd like to avoid

Comment: if you want it to be secure there's going to have to be some credential involved.

Comment: @erik258 i'm sure there's a safe way to do it without needing such APIs , ie apps such as discord dont use APIs yet they can safely send some datas to their server